# How to set up Script Variables in JIRA

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I read the following documentation on Script Variables in Script Runner (http://scriptrunner-docs.connect.adaptavist.com/jiracloud/script-variables.html) and how to use it in your script, but it does not describe how to set up a variable.

For example, in the documentation it say's that the variable

`MY_FIRST_SHARED_VAR`

has the value

`testValue`

but how do you set that variable and where do you do this? Do you set it up in JIRA or the server that is running JIRA?

Answer (score 0):

Go into the **Add-ons** part of JIRA Administration and in the left sidebar there should be a sub-heading **SCRIPTRUNNER** with one of the subsections being **Script Variables**. For a Cloud instance, the exact URL should be something like this:

`https://[yourinstance].atlassian.net/plugins/servlet/ac/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner/script-variables?s=com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner__script-variables`